# Setting a prototype property of an undeclared {object} inside an [array]

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
var Nest = [];
```

And I plan on filling it with objects like this

```
bird_id1 = /*gotten from some outer variable, say*/ 8;
bird_id2 =  9;
bird1 = Nest[bird_id1] = { id: bird_id1, ... }
bird2 = Nest[bird_id2] = { id: bird_id2, ... }
```

Now I was wondering if I could have the `bird`, or `= Nest[bird_idX]` have a predefined function set though prototype, such that I can call it like

```
bird1.chirp(this.id);
```

or

```
Nest[bird_id2].chirp(this.id);
```

So essentially the `chirp()` function has to be defined as a protptype on the `{Nest[]}` object (which is inside an array). How could that be done?

I would try the regular method of defining the prototype property

```
Nest[?].prototype = function chirp(){...}
```

But I'm not sure how

Comment: It **must** be an array or can be an object? like `var Nest = {}` then `Nest.chirp = function() { }` so your `Nest[bird_id1] = {}` will still work.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown It can be, but how will `Nest.chirp(this.id)` work? `this.id` has to be separate for each `bird` (which was the reason I thought I should make Nest an array)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown So it's not possible to set prototype of the object inside the array like that?

Comment: But what is `this`? It seems that its called outside a Nest object.

Comment: `bird` would be `this` (I thought?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the birds with a constructor:

```
// constructor
function Bird(id) {
  this.id = id;
}

// properties shared by all birds
Bird.prototype.chirp = function() {
  console.log('My id is: ' + this.id);
}

// nest
var Nest = [];
// ids
var bird_id_1 = 8, bird_id_2 = 9;

// create birds
Nest[bird_id_1] = new Bird(bird_id_1);
Nest[bird_id_2] = new Bird(bird_id_2);

// make them sing
Nest.forEach(function(bird){ bird.chirp(); });
```

Notice that while each bird has the same `chirp` method, the method doesn't need the id parameter to display different things. It simply acts on the data of the bird, in this case logging the id of the bird it was called on.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be create an Object Bird with that function in its prototype, and then use this object instances to fill your array:

```
var Bird = function(){};
Bird.prototype.chirp = function(id){};

var bird_id =  9;
bird1 = new Bird();
bird1.id = bird_id;

var Nest = [];
Nest[ bird_id ] = bird1;
```

And then you can easily use  your chirp function:

```
Nest[ bird_id ].chirp();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Bird` constructor:

```
function Bird(id) {
 this.id = id;
}
Bird.prototype.chirp = function () { /*chirpchirp*/ }
// subsequently
bird_id1 = /*gotten from some outer variable, say*/ 8;
bird_id2 =  9;
bird1 = Nest[bird_id1] = new Bird(bird_id1);
bird2 = Nest[bird_id2] = new Bird(bird_id2);
```